# How to build a RARP packet in C#?

Tags: c#, network-programming, arp

I have a task that requires me to receive a RARP request from the server (asking "Who has (00:00:00:00:00:00)", and then to respond to that Server with a RARP packet that resolves that MAC with an IP.

I understand how to resolve the IP address, but I am simply having problems building out the RARP packet to respond to my server in C#. There are few examples for RARP because it is an obsolete protocol, and I was just hoping someone in the community could point me in the right direction.

Please don't tell me I may want to try a different protocol. RARP is a requirement for this task.

Comment: Try this RARP implementation for C# https://github.com/madrugado/rarp

Comment: The code is using "iphlpapi.dll". You can get more documentation on this from pinvoke : http://www.pinvoke.net which gives all the library functions